# mpl data error with cx_freeze - Linux 13.10

Tags: python, linux, matplotlib, cx-freeze

I am new on stack overflow and I hope I am not asking something obvious. In fact, I did quite a search online and I could not find a proper answer/solution to my problem.

I am building an open-source cross-platform desktop application based on python. I am using cx_freeze to build a distribution version. The cx_freeze works well on Windows 7 and Mac OS X 10.9.2  and the app are already built. Nonetheless, when I try to use the same setup.py file to build the diet_version on Linux 13.10, I get the following error:

My building options are:

```
build_exe_options = {"includes":["matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg","sys","os","PyQt4","numpy","sys","os","matplotlib"],
                     "include_files":[(matplotlib.get_data_path(), 'mpl-data')],
                     "excludes":[],
                     }
```

and I get the following error:

```
error: build/exe.linux-x86_64-2.7/mpl-data: Is a directory
```

I tried to use the full path of mpl-data in the building options, i.e.

```
build_exe_options = {"includes":["matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg","sys","os","PyQt4","numpy","sys","os","matplotlib"],
                     "include_files":[("/usr/share/matplotlib/mpl-data", 'mpl-data'), ("/usr/share/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts", 'mpl-data/fonts'),("/usr/share/matplotlib/mpl-data/images", 'mpl-data/images'),("/etc/matplotlibrc", 'mpl-data')],
                     "excludes":[],
                     }
```

but I keep getting the same error mentioned above.

If I do not declare the build_exe options, as I did on Windows 7, I get the following error on Linux:

```
error: /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/mpl-data: No such file or directory
```

I am afraid the error happens because mpl-data is located in $/usr/share/matplotlib/mpl-data rather than $/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/mpl-data, but I have no clue why the error persists even after declaring the path to the folder.

To sum up, I release the desktop app for windows and mac os without any problems (works like a charm!), but the linux version is still pending a stand-alone version (check the Linux source code here: http://concrete.fsv.cvut.cz/~wilson/Software.html). Can anybody shed some light on this issue? How to tell cx_freeze to get the mpldata without errors.

Thanks in advance,

Wbr

Comment: Standalone applications aren't the norm on Linux - is it practical to make a package that depends on matplotlib?

Comment: My idea was just to build a "one click" file so user would not have to stress about having the right packages to run the application (Windows and Mac users would be more acquainted with this approach). As I mentioned, I already released the source codes so Linux user can run the app from terminal (I indicate the necessary packages to run it). The cx_freeze works like charm, even in Linux; nonetheless, when it involves matplotlib, the issues I mentioned in the first message arise. Any suggestion?

Comment: If you build a package properly, installing it will automatically install the things it depends on, so it is still 'one click'. Sorry, I don't know what could be causing the error you see.

Comment: That might be the problem... Build it properly? Does matplotlib dependency becomes an issue in my case? Things were smoother after I updated cx-freeze to 4.3.2, but I still get the same error message. Nonetheless, the standalone app works :-)

Comment: cx_Freeze doesn't handle dependencies, so by Linux distro standards, it doesn't make proper packages. However, if you've got something that works for you, that's great.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation! I will post an answer with the changes I had to do in order to make the executable work. It could be of some interest, who knows. Thanks again Thomas!

Comment: Hey, could you please post your answer for this? Exact same problem!